# Как отправить кириллицу в get-запросе в параметрах к request?

Tags: python, url, get, кириллица, request

```
paramsg = {
    "keywords" : "кладовщик")
}
html_page = requests.get(href, params=paramsg)
```

upd. проблема решилась когда написал "кладовщики" 
Вопрос стоял в том, чтобы парсить резюме с superjob, если ставить в единственном числе, то сайт перебрасывает на страницу "https://www.superjob.ru/resume/kladovschik.html", при этом не сохраняет параметры запроса. 
Изменил на "кладовщики" и запрос отправился верно.

Comment: Приведенный пример полностью рабочий. За исключением лишней скобки ) в конце второй строки.

Comment: @m9_psy не ясно, рабочий ли пример даже если скобку убрать: байтовая константа может не в utf-8 кодировке сохранена.

Comment: Добавьте `# coding=utf-8`, попробуйте ещё раз.

Comment: @NickVolynkin: без декларации кодировки была бы SyntaxError на Питон 2. Проблема (теоретически) могла быть что файл сохранён в кодировке несовместимой с декларированной. Но как обновление   показывает, вопрос вообще к Питону не имеет отношения.

Comment: Да, когда задавал вопрос, думал именно в кодировке в питоне дело